# Inject html into current page after pressing on extension icon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Need to inject HTML into page using google chrome extension. But this code must be injected after pressing on extension icon - when I click on icon HTML code inject into page and when I click on it next time this code should disappear.

Example: HTML Code

```
<html><head>
   <link href="HelloWorld.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="HelloWorld.js"></script>
</head><body>
<p>Hello World!</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far ? I suggest you take a look at http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html, you'll probably need this.

Comment: "content_scripts":          [ {
        "js":       [ "iframeInjector.js" ],
        "matches":  [   "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/*"
        ]
    } ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["Embedded_Hello_world.htm"]
___

Comment: So I can inject HTMLcode, but I want inject it only after click on extension's icon

Answer (score 1):

Use `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` API. Check more details [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked).